# Virtual Extension Methods in upcoming Java 8 release

Tags: java, interface, multiple-inheritance, java-8, diamond-problem

When I see code snippets like

```
  interface A {
      void a();
      void b() default { System.out.println("b"); };
      void c() final { System.out.println("c"); };
  }
```

I have one question. <s>Haven't we already got enough sh*t in Java?</s> Why one might need this?

Comment: This is a great extension imo, will bring Java closer to the world of multiple inheritance without all its messy implementation details.

Comment: @Perception "...without all its messy implementation details..." how exactly?

Comment: Constructor chaining, Potential name clashing, Polymorphic ambiguity, not too talk of the additional complexity that would need to be defined in the compiler. All reasons why mixins are more popular than multiple inheritance in alot of modern languages, and what this feature reminds me more of.

Comment: @Perception Sorry I asked how to avoid all this stuff, not what the stuff is.

Comment: No constructor chaining problems because there are none. And I'm guessing they will add explicit scope to overriden interface methods to avoid the naming/polymorphic ambiguity issue.

Comment: Few people use Java 7 and we worry about Java 8 ?

Comment: @SoboLAN As a Java progammer I have to worry about things like that.

Comment: It's a feature that API designers will love and that doesn't have to worry the average programmer much. And really? Java is one of the most basic modern languages around. Heck even **c++** had more changes in the last few years than java. Getting at least lambdas and real closure support is long overdue..

Comment: @Voo You're not going to see "real" or "pure" closures in JDK8. Other than much needed "syntactical sugar", behaviour is only different from inner classes in peculiar ways.

Comment: @Tom Wait we're not removing the limitation of not extending the scope of outer variables? I certainly do hope that's not true but I haven't looked at the jsr. That'd anticlimactic ~

Comment: How do you mean? Scope rules are as anonymous inner classes. There is no inner this. Referenced outer locals do not have to be marked final, but have to be used as if they are (in effect the final is implicit).

Comment: @Radu  1. Lots of people use Java 7.  If you're on Java EE 6 or you develop core java apps, you should be using it.   2. Continuous improvement is required to keep up with .NET, Ruby and other languages.  No matter how slow you are to switch, java still needs to release a new version every 18 months to 2 years

Comment: @GlenBest Look at the timestamp of my comment. Obviously things changed a bit since then. As for the fact that Java should release more frequently in order to stay competitive: I strongly agree. 2 years seems a good balance for this. I hope they'll stick to it in the future, because up until now it was kind of dissapointing: 4 and a half years from Java 6 to Java 7 and now it'll be 2 years and 8 months from Java 7 to Java 8....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you to look at this conference : http://medianetwork.oracle.com/media/show/16999

This explain everything. The most interesting thing to do is to allow an interface to evolve without rewritting your whole codebase. This is key to allow a big codebase to evolve and not become more and more crippled.

Answer (score 35):

We need this because it will make the Scala guys absolutely furious. They already have rather similar functionality in the shape of 'traits', so now they'll have to make those work together with these.

Pissing off Scala guys is literally the highest priority in Java language development.

Comment: Actually, I think virtual extension methods are a [very incomplete implementation](http://codecrafter.blogspot.ca/2012/06/java-8-virtual-extension-methods-are.html) of traits, and might paint itself into a corner.

Answer (score 13):

It is planned that Java 8 will contain some form of lambda and closure support, which would be a big step in modernizing the Java language. The problem is that existing libraries based on interfaces, like the collection framework, won't be able to directly use these new features. It is not possible to add a method to an interface without breaking existing implementations, they would simple no longer compile.

Having lambdas, but not being able to easily use them with standard collections, would be a huge letdown for java developers. To integrate lambdas into the standard collections, methods like `forEach`, `map`, or `filter` would be highly desirable.

The solution to this problem is to add another feature, extension methods, which define a default implementation of a method in a interface. Existing subclasses would use the default method, but it is also possible to override the method with a specialized and possible better implementation.

More information about the extension method proposal can be found at [Java Enhancement Proposal 126](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/126).

Comment: And for exactly the same reasons why they'll be so extremely useful for lambdas, they will also help other APIs. Finally no `interface X`, `X2`,.. any more! About time.

Answer (score 3):

This is great because it allows you, the API writer to post-hoc extend interfaces without causing NoSuchMethodErrors. It also You provide default implementations for methods in V2 for classes compiled against V1; code works like a charm. This also allows you to override the default implementation in classes compiled against V2 as usual, and makes numbered interafces redundant. I consider it also superior than use-site extension methods.

Comment: No, it's an aid for library writers, who can now extend their interfaces (APIs) in V1.1 without needing to rename it to 2.0 and requiring a recompile.

Comment: Ah, apologies - it's a tool for library writers that eases the API evolution of the libraries; library writers can extend their interfaces without the library users needing to modify their code.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that "extension methods" concept is no more than just the last chance to hack/fix poorly designed APIs which have been exposed to "external world". Just syntactic sugar.

Comment: Yeah all those poorly designed APIs whose designers weren't gifted with clairvoyance or couldn't actually design their interface differently because some features didn't already exist ;)

Comment: @Voo API designers don't need to be clairvoyant to realise that there might be methods that need to be added later. Could have used abstract classes, although the language is deficient in that it doesn't allow definition of a "pure" abstract class without adding the unwanted binary-compatibility baggage of an interface.

Comment: Oh, "defender methods" actually.

Comment: @TomHawtin Using abstract classes is not only problematic from a practical point of view, but also bad coding OOP style often enough. So clearly that's no solution for lots of situations.

Comment: @Voo Would have been perfect for collections, JDBC, etc. As for bad style, clearly their is something wrong with the "style" if it causes these sorts of problems. Oh, and what practical problems?? `AbstractCollection` has to go, and you go use `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`, but who cares.

Comment: @TomHawtin Practical problems? Well it makes it impossible to implement 2+ "interfaces" which certainly is limiting. And in general interfaces are way more used than abstract classes, so the change is welcome for lots of people and people who prefer abstract classes aren't affected anyhow. The change just just removes one of the most annoying problems with interfaces (now let us specify constructors too and I'd happy).

Comment: Implement 2+ interfaces? Is it often you want to inherit from a `Collection` or a `Statement` type together with another class?